# Turn Off Translucent Bars on SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, ios10, sfsafariviewcontroller

In iOS 10, Apple added the property PreferredBarTintColor to set the color of the NavigationBar at the top and TabBar at the bottom to match the color of your app.  Which is great, except that the bars have translucency turned on, which I prefer to have turned off in my app.

Is there a way to turn off this transparency, which causes the colors in my app to not match up?

The color of my app looks like below image

[image: The color of my app]

But SafariViewController looks like below one

[image: The color in SafariViewController]

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I have filed a bug report (30872324) for this.

Answer (score -7):

From iOS 11, Apple solved this problem and it should not be transparant anymore!

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I'm running an app right now with iOS 11 as the deployment target and I set the preferredBarTintColor to a very dark shade of blue-ish gray. It's still translucent. You can tell when you go to Apple's website and you scroll up/down because they have a white background with contrasting elements. I can see the translucency just fine and the alpha in my custom UIColor is set to 1.00 - so I know it isn't me.